# mono dllimport DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, mono, dllimport, filenotfoundexception

I'm currently tryng to port a windows/.NET 4.0 application in linux (Debian8) /mono, but i've some issues regarding p/invoke of some custom library.

here's my code:

```
[DllImport("FILE_Module.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr getVersioneLib();
```

then the function is called somewhere else in the code.

I also created, in debug path, exename.exe.config file with dllmap tag pointing to libFILE_Module.so, which is in /usr/local/lib, and ldconfig -p output seems ok.

I've also done another couple of attempts, as for instance

```
[DllImport("FILE_Module", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

but I can't move from receiving a DllNotFoundException

Any ideas? I'm surely missing something, but... What?

Thanks in advance, and best regards!